# ¿Cómo comprobar varios valores por un valor para identificar el producto adquirido?

Tags: php, mysqli

Obtenemos los ids de los productos (el identificador único) `primary` que es el `id_product`

```
$smtm = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product FROM products WHERE active=?");
$smtm->bind_param("i",$active);
$active = "1";
$smtm->execute();
$smtm->store_result();

if ($smtm->num_rows>0) {
  //Si existen registros en la tabla
  $smtm->bind_result($id_product);
  while ($smtmId->fetch()) {
    echo ''.$id_product.'';
  }
} else {
  //Si no existe registros en la tabla
  echo "No se encontro registro";
}
```

Ahora la comprobación si un usuario compro o no un producto se verifica mediante el `if (checkSubscribeComplete($id_product) === true){}` comprobando con los ids que contiene la variable `$id_product`

> Los datos que recibe la variable `$id_product` **es:** `12345678910`

**Apunte a la problemática** La variable `$id_product` esta tomando un valor `12345678910` y no lo es, es un resultado que contendrá los valores `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, y `10` que al escribirlos sin separación dentro de un bucle se ven como un `12345678910`

> Ahora recordando que la comprobación `if (checkSubscribeComplete($id_product) === true) {}` comprueba si un usuario tiene un producto o más de un producto comprado, **el problema** es que la comprobación está recibiendo el siguiente dato `12345678910` y lo esta comprobando en su consulta como si fuera un `id` de un producto cuando no lo es.

**Ejemplo:** el producto que esta buscando ***(y este producto no existe)***

```
|  id_product  | product | active |
   12345678910     x         1
```

**La comprobación:**

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete($id_product) === true){}
```

**Recibe lo siguiente:**

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete(12345678910) === true){}
```

Por lo tanto la verificación siempre sera falso `false` porque esta recibiendo datos erróneos.

**¿Cómo comprobar un valor por valor para identificar el producto adquirido?**

Es decir enviar dato a la comprobación de la siguiente manera:

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete(1) === true){}
```

y así sucesivamente:

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete(2) === true){}
```

o de la siguiente manera:

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) === true){}
```

En ves de que se envié los datos de esta manera:

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete(12345678910) === true){}
```

*Tengo un usuario que compro un producto, un producto con un `id` (uno) `1`

La `Fuction` para comprobar si un usuario tiene productos comprados.

```
function checkSubscribeComplete($id_product){
  global $con;
  global $id_user;
  $res = false; // the default result
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT status FROM order WHERE id_product=? AND UserId=? AND status = ?"); 
  $stmt->bind_param("iis",$id_product,$UserId,$status); 
  $status='complete'; 
  $stmt->execute(); 

  $stmt->store_result(); 

  if ($stmt->num_rows ===1){
    $res = true;
  } else {
    $res = false;
  }
  return $res;
}
```

**¿Qué es lo que quiero hacer?**

En la página catalogo de productos voy a mostrar todos los productos de la taba `products` ahora si un usuario inicia sesión al sistema y si no tiene productos comprados los productos se mostraran sin ningún cambio, igualmente sucederá cuando no existen usuarios logueados al sistema, pero si un usuario tiene uno o más productos comprados en la lista de productos del catalogo quiero ocultar el precio de aquel producto que el usuario haya comprado y mostrar otro dato en vez del precio.

**Pero no logro mostrar los resultados deseados:**

```
$smtm = $con->prepare("SELECT product,price FROM products WHERE active=? order by id_product ASC");
$smtm->bind_param("i",$active);
$active = "1";

$smtm->execute();
$smtm->store_result();

if ($smtm->num_rows>0) {
  $smtm->bind_result($product, $price);
  while ($smtm->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="all-description">
     <h2>'.$product.'</h2>';

       if (checkSubscribeComplete($id_product) === true) {
        echo '<a href="#">Ver factura</a>';
        echo '<h2>'.$product.'</h2>';
        echo 'Producto comprado :)';

       } else {
        //Si el producto no esta comprado mostramos el precio del producto
        echo '<h3>'.$price.'</h3>';
       }

     echo'
    </div>
    </div>';
    echo '';
  }
} else {
  echo "No existen productos";
}
```

Comment: `$id_product` no es 12, es un resultset que contendrá los valores 1 y 2 que al escribirlos sin separación dentro de un bucle se ven como un 12. No me termina de quedar claro por qué no puedes hacer la comprobación en cada pasada del bucle (o en una select propia) en lugar de concatenar los valores en uno que no existe.

Comment: no entiendo nada. para que preguntas por el estado "SELECT status FROM subscribed WHERE id_product=? AND UserId=? AND status = ?" si lo devuelves como resultado? que estas tratando de hacer? que tiene que ver la tabla que mostras con este query? parece completa la pregutna, pero tambien parece que falta informacion sobre que quieres hacer, mas alla de lo que hiciste.. para mi, falta explicar que se quiere resolver, mas que como se intento...

Comment: hay una mezcla de cosas.. muestras funciones, pero no se ni como se ejecutan ni el orden de las mismas.. porque no aclaras tu problema en español simple, a ver si podemos arrancar por ahi? veo que desarrollaste un monton, definitivamente el problema no esta ahi.. por ejemplo, de donde sale $id_courses en la ultima funcion que escribiste?

Comment: Te dije en un comentario en la anterior pregunta que **probaras con datos reales puestos manualmente**, es decir, datos que existan en la base de datos y creo que me dijiste que lo habías hecho. Esa es una de las primeras pruebas de depuración que hay que hacer. Toma nota para futuros problemas. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Comment: @A.Cedano pero resolvio el problema? y pq sigue abierta la pregunta?

Comment: Por otra parte, vi que borraste la anterior pregunta en la cual había bastante información útil para resolver el problema. No me parece una buena idea.

Comment: @gbianchi eso he interpretado yo al leer el primer comentario, donde dice que encontró el error. Para mi encontrar el error es indicativo de problema resuelto.

Comment: Oscar me pasé un buen rato contigo hace unos días tratando de arreglar una sola función de tu código  y he llegado a la conclusión de que tienes un serio problema de lógica en tu programa, sugiero que te sientes de nuevo y pienses una mejor lógica para tu programa y no una lógica que se adapte a tus conocimientos. En programación _casi todo es posible_  aunque no sepas como hacerlo. Si no lo sabes, lo preguntas (para eso existe este sitio). Plantéate con claridad cuál debería ser la lógica y si no logras realizarla, entonces pregunta _cómo puedo hacer esto o aquello_.

Comment: Todavía está abierta la pregunta?... no sería más fácil usar join para ver si el producto ya fue comprado por el usuario?... Aparte, evitarías ejecutar las consultas adicionales que tienes actualmente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Han realizado una tormenta en un vaso de agua, se han complicado pero así es el amor a la programación :)

Vamos por parte

**¿Cómo comprobar un valor por valor para identificar el producto adquirido?**

Para obtener este resultado

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) === true){}
```

Se deben realizar cambios en la consulta, de la siguiente forma:

```
$array = array();
if ($smtmId->num_rows>0) {
  //Si existen registros en la tabla de la base de datos mostramos los resultados
  $smtmId->bind_result($id_product);
  while ($smtmId->fetch()) {
    $array[] = $id_product;
    //echo ''.$id_product.'';
  }
} else {
  //Si no existe registros en la base de datos mostramos un mensaje de error.
  echo "No se encontro registro";
}
```

Debes cambiar en la comprobación el `$id_product` por lo siguiente `$array`

```
if (checkSubscribeComplete($array) === true){}
```

Ahora recibirás los datos de siguiente forma `1`, `2`, `3`...

Ahora para solucionar el problema del catalogo de productos.

Debes modificar la consulta a:

```
$smtm = $con->prepare("SELECT id_product,product,price FROM products WHERE active=? order by id_product ASC");
```

Ahora para que puedas ocultar el precio del producto que un usuario haya comprado debes hacer el siguiente cambio.

```
if ($smtm->num_rows>0) {
  $smtm->bind_result($id_product, $product, $price);
  while ($smtm->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="four-column middle-pro">
    <div class="all-description">
     <h2>'.$product.'</h2>';

       if (checkSubscribeComplete(['id_product'])) { 
       //if (checkSubscribeComplete(1) === true) {
        echo 'producto comprado';
        echo '<a href="#">Descargar factura</a>';

       } else {
        //Si el producto no esta comprado mostramos el precio del producto
        echo '<h3>'.$price.'</h3>';
       }

     echo'
    </div>
    </div>';
    echo '';
  }
}
```

Suerte :)

Comment: Amigo funciona :) tal como deseaba gracias.

Comment: Mi punto de vista es que no es necesario comprobar por productos sino por usuario. Una solución así se caerá cuando el programa crezca, cuando el mismo usuario haga compras en fechas diferentes, etc. Yo he querido aportar una solución global al problema, indicando que en el código, como estaba planteado inicialmente había errores de lógica que dificultan una solución, no solamente a mediano plazo, sino también una solución que sea óptima y válida en cualquier escenario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Caerá el programa lo dices por recibir los datos así `if (checkSubscribeComplete(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) === true){}` pueda que tengas razón al existir unos 100 productos por ejemplo pero solo dí solución como obtener los datos de esa manera. **Ahora la solución única en fin es la siguiente** `if (checkSubscribeComplete(['id_product'])) {}` que es lo mismo que dices porque si te das cuenta la consulta que tiene la `function` es tabla `order` y lo que se comprueba en aquella tabla es el id del producto y el id del usuario y el estado del pedido.

Comment: @A.Cedano  En resumen la consulta `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT status FROM order WHERE id_product=? AND UserId=? AND status = ?");` es lo mismo que comprobar por usuario porque se obtiene dos datos el id del producto y el id del usuario que ha iniciado sesión por decir la consulta sería así o así se reciben los datos:  `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT status FROM order WHERE id_product=1 AND UserId=1 AND status = complete");`

Comment: @JDoe me refería a eso y también al diseño mismo de las tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano La siguiente comprobación `if (checkSubscribeComplete(['id_product'])) {}` el resultado a recibir será individualmente así recibirá los datos:  `if (checkSubscribeComplete(1) === true){}` y `if (checkSubscribeComplete(2) === true){}`

Answer (score 3):

### EDICIÓN INCLUYENDO PRUEBA DE CONCEPTO, MOSTRANDO LO QUE TE DIJE EN VARIOS COMENTARIOS

He reproducido tu programa en un escenario real.

Esta es mi propuesta.

Puesto que quieres mostrar todos los productos, haremos dos consultas a la base de datos y almacenaremos sus resultados en un array:

- Una para obtener todos los productos de la tabla productos:

  ```
  $sqlProductos=
  "SELECT producto_id, producto_nom, producto_precio, producto_img, producto_detalle  
   FROM productos_20171005";
  ```

El resultado de esta consulta será el siguiente array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [producto_id] => 1
            [producto_nom] => Camisa
            [producto_precio] => 35.00
            [producto_img] => http://atlasstoked.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/9/2/926094_1.jpg
            [producto_detalle] => 50% algodón... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [producto_id] => 2
            [producto_nom] => Pantalón corto
            [producto_precio] => 15.00
            [producto_img] => https://www.laropanatural.com/2298-home_default/pantalon-bermuda-deporte-algodon.jpg
            [producto_detalle] => 50% polyester... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [producto_id] => 3
            [producto_nom] => Zapatos de mujer
            [producto_precio] => 49.99
            [producto_img] => https://www.marlosonline.es/55152-home_default/zapatos-marlos-feelings-mary-jane.jpg
            [producto_detalle] => 51% piel... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [producto_id] => 4
            [producto_nom] => Bolso de mujer
            [producto_precio] => 99.99
            [producto_img] => https://www.brochbroch.com/1137-medium_default/bolso-de-mano-mediterranean-miel.jpg
            [producto_detalle] => 100% ecológico hecho en China... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

)
```

- Otra consulta para obtener los ids de productos que el usuario haya comprado. Usaremos como ejemplo al usuario 1, que compró los productos 1 y 3.

  ```
  $sqlUsuario=
  "SELECT prd.producto_id  
    FROM ordenes_detalles_20171005 odt
    INNER JOIN ordenes_20171005 ord ON odt.orden_id=ord.orden_id 
    INNER  JOIN productos_20171005 prd ON odt.producto_id=prd.producto_id 
    INNER JOIN usuarios_20171005 usr ON ord.usuario_id=usr.usuario_id 
    WHERE usr.usuario_id=?  AND prd.producto_active=TRUE
    GROUP BY prd.producto_id";
  ```

**Notas**:

1. He guardado el diseño de tablas que te comenté más abajo, al ver que en la tabla `ordenes` tenías una columna fecha. Si no creas una tabla `ordenes_detalles`  tendrás que repetir esa columna fecha en la tabla `ordenes` por cada producto comprado en una misma orden innecesariamente.
2. Ignoro para que sirve la columna `active`. Sospecho que no tiene ninguna utilidad aquí. Pero eso es lo de menos.

El resultado de esa consulta es el siguiente array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [producto_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [producto_id] => 3
        )

)
```

Luego leeremos el array de todos los productos, y haremos una comparación con el array de los productos que el usuario ha comprado.  Si encontramos en ese array algún id de producto, cambiaremos el código HTML.

Lo hacemos en este trozo de código:

```
$strHTML="";
foreach ($arrProductos as $row){
        $intProductoId=$row['producto_id'];
        $strProductoNombre=$row['producto_nom'];
        $strProductoDetalle=$row['producto_detalle'];
        $strProductoImg=$row['producto_img'];

        $strProductoImg='<img src="'.$strProductoImg.'">';
        /*MUY IMPORTANTE*/
        if(in_array($intProductoId, array_column($arrDatos, 'producto_id'))) { 
           $strProductoPrecio="Ver factura"; 
        }else{
            $strProductoPrecio=$row['producto_precio'];
        }
        $strHTML.=$strProductoImg.'<h2>'
         .$strProductoPrecio.'</h2>'
         .$strProductoNombre.'<br />'
         .$strProductoDetalle.'<hr />';    
}
echo $strHTML;
```

El resultado será parecido al que muestras en tu imagen. En la prueba de concepto el usuario 1 ha comprado los productos 1 y 3. Verás que dice **Ver factura**, mientras que en los otros, se muestra el precio.

Claro está, no he aplicado reglas CSS ni nada de eso, ese será tu trabajo. Tampoco he puesto enlaces a *Ver factura*... todo lo que queda es lo de menos, sólo cambias el valor de las variables.

### Resultado:

```html
<img src="http://atlasstoked.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/9/2/926094_1.jpg"><h2>Ver factura</h2>Camisa<br />50% algodón... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<hr /><img src="https://www.laropanatural.com/2298-home_default/pantalon-bermuda-deporte-algodon.jpg"><h2>15.00</h2>Pantalón corto<br />50% polyester... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<hr /><img src="https://www.marlosonline.es/55152-home_default/zapatos-marlos-feelings-mary-jane.jpg"><h2>Ver factura</h2>Zapatos de mujer<br />51% piel... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<hr /><img src="https://www.brochbroch.com/1137-medium_default/bolso-de-mano-mediterranean-miel.jpg"><h2>99.99</h2>Bolso de mujer<br />100% ecológico hecho en China... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<hr /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

### Datos usados para la prueba

#### Tablas:

```
$sqlCreateProductos=
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos_20171005
    (
        producto_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        producto_nom VARCHAR(70),
        producto_img VARCHAR(200),
        producto_precio  DECIMAL (12,2),
        producto_detalle VARCHAR(200),
        producto_active  BOOLEAN
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";

$sqlInsertProductos=
    "INSERT INTO productos_20171005 (producto_nom,producto_img,producto_precio,producto_detalle,producto_active)
        VALUES (
        'Bolso de mujer',
        'https://www.brochbroch.com/1137-medium_default/bolso-de-mano-mediterranean-miel.jpg',
        '99.99',
        '100% ecológico hecho en China... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        TRUE)";

$sqlCreateUsuario=
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios_20171005
    (
        usuario_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        usuario_nom VARCHAR(70)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";

$sqlInsertUsuario=
    "INSERT INTO usuarios_20171005 
    (usuario_nom)
    VALUES ('Pedro'),('Santiago'),('Juan')";


$sqlCreateOrden=
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ordenes_20171005
    (
        orden_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        usuario_id INT,
        orden_fecha DATETIME,
        UNIQUE INDEX  (orden_fecha,usuario_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios_20171005(usuario_id)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;";

$sqlInsertOrdenes=
    "INSERT INTO ordenes_20171005 
    (usuario_id, orden_fecha)
    VALUES (1,'2017-09-30'),(2,'2017-10-01'),(3,'2017-10-05')";


$sqlCreateOrdenDetalles="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ordenes_detalles_20171005
    (
        orden_id INT, 
        producto_id INT,
        cantidad INT,
        UNIQUE INDEX  (orden_id,producto_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (orden_id) REFERENCES ordenes_20171005(orden_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (producto_id) REFERENCES productos_20171005(producto_id)

    )ENGINE=INNODB;";

$sqlInsertOrdenesDetalles="INSERT INTO ordenes_detalles_20171005 
    (orden_id, producto_id, cantidad)
    VALUES (1,1,10),(1,3,33),(2,2,15),(3,1,3)";
```

### Código PHP

```
/*Seleccionar todos  los  productos*/
$sqlProductos=
    "SELECT producto_id, producto_nom, producto_precio, producto_img, producto_detalle  
     FROM productos_20171005";


$stmt=$mysqli->query($sqlProductos);

while ($fila=$stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    $arrProductos[]=$fila;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrProductos);

/*Seleccionar todos  los  productos comprados por el usuario*/

    $sqlUsuario=
    "SELECT prd.producto_id   
          FROM ordenes_detalles_20171005 odt
          INNER JOIN ordenes_20171005 ord ON odt.orden_id=ord.orden_id 
          INNER  JOIN productos_20171005 prd ON odt.producto_id=prd.producto_id 
          INNER JOIN usuarios_20171005 usr ON ord.usuario_id=usr.usuario_id 
          WHERE usr.usuario_id=?  AND prd.producto_active=TRUE
          GROUP BY prd.producto_id";

$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sqlUsuario);
if ($stmt) {
    /*
      * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
      * Ejecutar
      * Almacenar los resultados
    */
    $id_usuario=1;
    $active="TRUE";
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id_usuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$producto, $precio,$imagen);    
    $stmt->store_result();

    $arrDatos=array();
    while ($fila=$stmt->fetch()){
        $arrDatos[]=array("producto_id"=>$id);
    }

    print_r($arrDatos);

    $strHTML="";
    foreach ($arrProductos as $row){
            $intProductoId=$row['producto_id'];
            $strProductoNombre=$row['producto_nom'];
            $strProductoDetalle=$row['producto_detalle'];
            $strProductoImg=$row['producto_img'];

            $strProductoImg='<img src="'.$strProductoImg.'">';
            /*MUY IMPORTANTE*/
            if(in_array($intProductoId, array_column($arrDatos, 'producto_id'))) { 
               $strProductoPrecio="Ver factura"; 
            }else{
                $strProductoPrecio=$row['producto_precio'];
            }
            $strHTML.=$strProductoImg.'<h2>'
             .$strProductoPrecio.'</h2>'
             .$strProductoNombre.'<br />'
             .$strProductoDetalle.'<hr />';    
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    echo $strHTML;
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "Error preparando  consulta".$mysqli->error;
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

---

### RESPUESTA ANTERIOR CON INFORMACIÓN TAMBIÉN VÁLIDA

Después de unos cuantos comentarios en esta y en [otra pregunta que fue eliminada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106424/error-en-mostrar-enlace-de-descarga), me animo a responderte (parcialmente).

La verdad es que, sin ánimo de ofender, mientras más te explicas, menos te entiendo :)

De todo lo que he leído, he entendido que lo que quieres es identificar los productos que el usuario ha comprado. Si los ha comprado, quieres mostrarlos, pero indicando un enlace de descarga del producto.

En un comentario te hablaba de que hay un error de lógica con respecto a la forma en que estás concibiendo el programa.

**¿Dónde está el error de lógica?**

En que tú quieres consultar por `id_producto`,  cuando en realidad deberías consultar por `id_usuario`,  traer todos los productos que el usuario ha comprado y mostrarlos con su respectivo enlace.

**Además de un error de lógica, tienes (intuyo) un error de diseño de datos**

Deberías tener una tabla `usuarios`,  una tabla `productos`, pero además una tabla `compras` y otra `compras_detalles` por llamarla de alguna manera. La constitución de dichas tablas sería más o menos esta.

**usuarios**

- `id_usuario`
- `usuario`

**productos**

- `id_producto`
- `producto`
- `precio`
- `url`
- `url_img`

**compras**

- `id_compra`
- `fecha_compra`
- `id_usuario`

**compras_detalles**

- `id_compra`
- `id_producto`
- `cantidad`

Veamos un pseudo_código:

1. Obtener id de usuario
2. Enviar consulta a la base de datos para que obtenga los id de productos comprados por ese usuario
3. Mostrar los productos retornados con su enlace de descarga

La función sería algo como esto:

Voy a usar datos ficticios... Debes adaptarlos.

```
function obtenerProductos ($id_usuario)
{
    $sql="SELECT pr.producto, pr.precio, pr.url, pr.url_img  
          FROM compras_detalles cd
          INNER JOIN compras co ON cd.id_compra=co.id_compra 
          INNER JOIN productos pr ON cd.id_producto=pr.id_producto 
          INNER JOIN usuarios us ON co.id_usuario=us.id_usuario 
          WHERE us.id_usuario=? AND activo=? 
          GROUP BY pr.id_producto"; 

    $active = 1;
    $smtm = $con->prepare($sql);
    $smtm->bind_param("ii",$id_usuario,$active);

    /*
     *MUY IMPORTANTE: Aquí obtendrías TODOS los productos comprados por el usuario X
     *construirías las url de los productos, mostrarías el precio, etc
     *Es un punto esencial de la lógica de tu programa que está fallando
     *Tú has pensando la lógica al revés: consultar por cada producto, 
     *cuando debes consultar por usuario
     */
    while ($fila = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo $fila["url"];
    }

    //Resto del código, cierre de recursos y demás

}
```

**Cómo llamar esa función pasándole datos dinámicos**

Esa era una de tus preguntas.

La función la llamas desde donde obtienes el id del usuario.

Por ejemplo:

```
/*Supongamos que lo obtienes por POST... me ahorro el isset por brevedad*/
$id_usuario=$_POST["id_usuario"]; //Supongamos que el valor es 2
obtenerProductos ($id_usuario);   //Llamamos la función para que encuentre los productos comprados por el usuario 2
```

Ahí estás llamando la función y pasándole el id de usuario actual.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66609/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-comprobar-varios-valores-por-un-valor-pa).

Comment: @A.Cedano el active es para activar un producto es decir en vez de eliminar el producto en la base de datos procedo a desactivarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano un + 1 por el esfuerzo y dedicación amigo :) gracias, pero la respuesta que dio [J. Doe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106209/c%C3%B3mo-comprobar-varios-valores-por-un-valor-para-identificar-el-producto-adquiri/107423#107423) soluciono mi problema.

Comment: @Oscar, me parece haber aportado una solución global a tu problema, el cual se ha hecho más grande debido a un error de lógica y de concepción sobre cómo debería funcionar tu aplicación. En cuanto leí el resumen de lo que querías entendí que la mejor solución era obtener todos los productos y luego comparar en la tabla  `orders` qué productos ha comprado el usuario. Me temo que no alcanzas a entender del todo lo que te he explicado, aún usando una prueba de concepto y me temo que te veremos por aquí de nuevo cuando tu programa se complique, cuando el mismo usuario haga más compras etc, etc.